# How to use specific iOS version on Azure hosted agent?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, azure, azure-devops

I have a requirement to use exactly iOS 14.5 on our pipeline.

I tried the following:

```
variables:
  sdk: 'iphoneos14.5' // I also tried to iphoneos

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'test'
    configuration: '$(configuration)'
    sdk: '$(sdk)'
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyProject.xcworkspace'
    scheme: '$(secondaryScheme)'
    xcodeVersion: 'specifyPath'
    xcodeDeveloperDir: '/Applications/Xcode_13.2.1.app'
    packageApp: false
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'
    destinationSimulators: 'iPhone 11,OS=14.5'
    args: '-derivedDataPath $(agent.buildDirectory)/DerivedData'
```

But both runs failed with

```
xcodebuild: error: SDK "iphoneos14.5" cannot be located.
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 64
```

And

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 }
```

That's what I understood from reading the preinstalled software documentation. https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-11-Readme.md

Grateful if you could tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do not leave any more comments about downvotes. Users are not expected to (in fact, they are discouraged from) leaving comments to go along with their votes. Voting is anonymous, and serves strictly as a content-rating system. Further comments about downvotes will be deleted on-sight, without a warning.

Comment: No, you're wrong. Stackoverflow itself show big and obvious popup saying  `please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved`  as soon as they click on the downvote button https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373  I don't know where you get this info that `Users are discouraged from` which completely the opposite of the implemented mechanism.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/xcode?view=azure-devops

 xcodeVersion: 'default' # Options: 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, default, specifyPath

this are the versions available i cant see version 14.05 on any docs
@TSR

Comment: From [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285777), which clearly states that, "No," users are not supposed to explain their downvotes. Note that the answer was written by someone who was a staff member at the time. I would also point you to the diamond following my user name if you need an authoritative source. At any rate, what I said is that *you* are not allowed to leave comments interrogating hypothetical downvoters, like the one which I deleted.

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow I also post the answer, you can check.

Answer (score 4):

By using your pipeline definition, I am able to reproduce your issue.

[image]

I think below YAML file will help you understand why the official document said 'iOS 14.5' is supported but you can't use it.

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘secondaryScheme’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- script: |
   xcodebuild -showsdks
   
   echo "========================================================="
   
   sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_12.5.1.app/Contents/Developer
   
   xcodebuild -showsdks
  displayName: 'Command Line Script'
```

When you see the result of the pipeline run, I believe you will understand everything：

[image]

After switching the version, you should be able to use the specific IOS version you want.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow

> You upload your app for notarization using notarytool command line
> tool. Xcode 13 or later supports this tool, so if you have more than
> one version of Xcode installed on your Mac, be sure to use the
> xcode-select utility to choose an appropriate version:
>
> % sudo xcode-select -s /path/to/Xcode13.app

Answer (score 1):

Added this step

```
gem install xcode-install
xcversion simulators --install='iOS 13.5'
```

If someone finds a way to use the installed sdk for other Xcode, please comment here

Comment: Hi TSR, have you tried this command `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode_12.5.1.app/Contents/Developer` that I posted in my answer, does it work on your side? And do you want to use IOS14.5 or IOS 13.5?